# OpenOffice default templates: how to distribute/deploy/install them for many users

Tags: templates, openoffice.org

I'm an IT admin for a sizable organization. We have developed default templates for Open Office Calc and Writer that conform to our branding and stylistic standards. I would like it to be the case that every user begins with these templates upon starting a new document. I would also like for it to be easy to distribute a new version of these templates when the time comes that we would like updates made to them. I understand how to set the default template for one user, but this process becomes far less feasible when scaled to dozens of users.

Any ideas? I'm open to writing a script that would need to be run on each machine or perhaps run for each user upon login, but I'm not sure how that script would access the user's OOo settings to set the default template. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of raising this question on the user forums such as http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/index.php ?